# GetStringAsync last too long and never returns

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, httpclient

I am developing and app that consume APIs (Using genymotion emulator for testing), I´ve made a simple test content page  in which behind code I have the next:

```
using PlaqueoApp.Modelos;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace PlaqueoApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class RegistrarPatron : ContentPage
    {
        public RegistrarPatron ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            GetOficinas().Wait();

        }

        private async Task GetOficinas()
        {
            Ping myPing = new Ping();
            PingReply reply = myPing.Send("8.8.8.8", 10000);


            HttpClient cliente = new HttpClient();

            string url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";

            var response = await cliente.GetStringAsync(url);

            var anonimus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(response);


        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that, when it reaches GetStringAsync it last forever, I mean, the method call never returns and I have to stop it.
This is what the response should look like:

```
{
  "page": 2,
  "per_page": 3,
  "total": 12,
  "total_pages": 4,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "Eve",
      "last_name": "Holt",
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "email": "charles.morris@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "Charles",
      "last_name": "Morris",
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "email": "tracey.ramos@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "Tracey",
      "last_name": "Ramos",
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought it was because Iternet connection but I checked Gennymotion emulator, and WIFI option is enable. I also made a ping to google as you can see and I get Success status, I also add Internet permission on Manifest.
I don´t know if I am missing something, if is something on Debugging my app or anything else

Comment: Hi, my problem is that, the flow never gets there, It´s like it never finish on waiting for Get request

Comment: try loading the url in the emulator's browser

Comment: You shouldn't be using `.Wait()`, this will block until the task completes. I assume that this application is using a synchronization context that is related to how Windows does this, message-based. Since you're effectively blocking the main thread until the task completes, the completion of the task queues up an action to be executed, and this is never executed because you're blocking the processing of messages and events. Remove `.Wait()` and find a better async way of doing what you want.

Comment: Hi @LasseVågsætherKarlsen. The problem is that when flows reaches GetStringAsync it does not get completed (When I am debuggin it gets our of the method or get ir completed), l think because the main thread continues an because the client is waiting for a response.

Comment: That problem is almost certainly due to that wait, you're blocking the synchronization context, which means tasks will stay in limbo forever.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, I just removed .Wait() , but the Get request is not working yet.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yeah, you were right, some how when I remove it worked, I don´t know if it was some network issues, Now I am getting a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
        public RegistrarPatron ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            GetOficinas().Wait();
        }
```

You should almost never Wait() on a Task like this: it will freeze your app or block a thread forever.

Do this instead:

```
namespace PlaqueoApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class RegistrarPatron : ContentPage
    {
        public RegistrarPatron ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            try 
            {
                await GetOficinas();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }   
        }

        private async Task GetOficinas()
        {
            Ping myPing = new Ping();
            PingReply reply = myPing.Send("8.8.8.8", 10000);

            HttpClient cliente = new HttpClient();

            string url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";

            var response = await cliente.GetStringAsync(url);

            var anonimus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked, It´s just that I´ve already remove .Wait() and it did not worked, I don´t know if this was some network adapter issue.

Comment: @MaxPower: Here's an explanation of how [locking on asynchronous code can cause deadlocks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Answer (score 0):

Modify the timeout on the `HttpClient` named `cliente` before making the request and add a `try/catch` block around the request to see what's going on.

If you have a separate async method that makes the call, you can put the try/catch in there and then call the separate method.  Otherwise, Call `.Wait()` on the task before wrapping exception handling around it.  The `Wait()` would be for testing purposes and not production use.